# Deployed asp.net mvc 3 RTM site to host, getting razor view must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel> errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here's the error I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Views/Home/Root.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
```

Runs fine on local dev box. Publish to host, errors galore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is mvc 3 installed on the host?  if not, do you have your mvc 3 assemblies set to "copy local" when building your app?

using mvc 3 in server environment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx

using mvc 3 in server that doesn't have mvc 3 installed in GAC: http://drew-prog.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-deploy-aspnet-mvc-3-app-to-web.html

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, I did copy bin files... I'm trying a completely fresh deployment again, using built in visual studio 2010 ftp deployment. I wonder if it has to do with the web.release.config transformation?

Comment: It could if you have transformations in web.release.config that touch anything you might pointing to a webpages related assembly?  Possibly in the system.web > compilation > assemblies tag?  Random guess here

Comment: strange, ftp deployment worked... guess I was missing something, though I don't know what. Thanks again for the SUPER fast response.